# How do I connect my raspberry pi to an app?

Tags: raspbian

I've created an app on App Inventor 2, and have coded my RP, but I am wondering how I connect my RP to my app, so I can control it with my app. The code on my pi is to control a lighting system where the user can turn the light on, off or auto. The auto setting is when the pi detects movement through a PIR, it turns the light on, and after a selected period of time the lights turns off. The app is used to change the settings on the lights, whether the light stays permanently on or off, or auto, where the user can control the time it takes before it turns off

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What does the app do? what do you mean by connect? What have you tried? Are you following a tutorial - if so can you include a link? I am afraid We will need a lot more detail if we are to help solve the problem.

Comment: can you take it off hold as i have editied it now? thanks

Comment: What is your app running on? That will be the key determiner of how it might be connected.

Comment: Your going to need to send a command from your app to a webpage or the file system on the Pi. So you need to find a way to use Bluetooth or WiFi to connect your  Pi and the device running your app. The Pi will need to receive this data and act upon it. A little searching on this site and Google may give you some things to try. Creating a web page on the Pi may be the easiest and also allow controlling the settings from any web browser that can access your page.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this. You can use web api's (commonly called rest api's) and have the software on your pi receive HTTP requests (search webserver in x language). You can raw TCP or UDP connections (search listen on tcp/udp port in x language) and communicate over a socket. You can also use blutooth and communicate that way, however that may be more complicated then you might think.

Depending on your need and usecase, you may find projects like XMPP and matrix (https://matrix.org) useful as you don't have to run a server on your pi, allowing for easier communication across different networks. While matrix is primarily used as a chat system, it was designed to allow many types of communication to be used on top of it such as IoT systems. XMPP is more complex then matrix to use in my opinion, but may be slightly more flexible.